# Disable CSRF protection in form generated by Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

In Sonata Admin I need to disable the CSRF token in some of my forms but sometimes I don't want to create a Form Type class, choosing instead to let Sonata generate the form, as such:

```
/** @var $form \Symfony\Component\Form\Form */
$form = $this->admin->getForm();
```

How can I disable the CSRF token from this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a Form Type class, the best way to change the CSRF field would be in the admin Class. For that, it's possible to override this function:

```
public function getFormBuilder() {
    $this->formOptions['data_class'] = $this->getClass();
    $this->formOptions['csrf_protection'] = false;
    $formBuilder = $this->getFormContractor()->getFormBuilder(
        $this->getUniqid(),
        $this->formOptions
    );
    $this->defineFormBuilder($formBuilder);
    return $formBuilder;
}
```

Comment: in MyBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin.php
Thnx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since Sonata Admin 4 (and deprecated in 3) the `getFormBuilder()` method is `final`. You can disable the CSRF token in the form options via `configureFormOptions()`:

```php
public function configureFormOptions(array &$formOptions): void
{
    $formOptions['csrf_protection'] = false;
}
```

I myself had to disable it (temporarily, don't worry) for the whole Sonata Admin, so I did this through a global Admin Extension:

In my `services.yaml`:

```yaml
    App\Admin\Extension\DisableCsrfProtectionExtension:
        tags: [{ name: 'sonata.admin.extension', global: true }]
```

In `src/Admin/Extension/DisableCsrfProtectionExtension.php`:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Admin\Extension;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdminExtension;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminInterface;

class DisableCsrfProtectionExtension extends AbstractAdminExtension {
    public function configureFormOptions(AdminInterface $admin, array &$formOptions): void {
        $formOptions['csrf_protection'] = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible as from `\Symfony\Component\Form\Form` instance you have access to object (`$form->getConfig()`) that implements `FormConfigInterface`: you can call on it `getOptions` or `getOption` but there is no `setOption` method.

Comment: Maybe there's some other way without having to disable CSRF token protection in the whole app