# The CSRF token is invalid

Tags: sonata-admin

i'm working with sonata admin bundle and the form view built with admin class
when i click on submit button of the form view  to send data i get this error:
**The CSRF token is invalid. Please return the form.**
thanks for your help.

Comment: Please write the title in English too.

Comment: it's done @JJJ !

Comment: Please include the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF is short for [Cross Site Request Forgery](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). That's a certain type of web based attacks that websites try to protect against by limiting from which web domains the site can be used from.

Somewhere in your site's settings you should be able to specify a list of trusted domains/addresses .
Make sure the site's actual domain is in that list or disable CSFR protection entirely (not recommended).

Hm. Might be more complicated than that actually. 
[Disable CSRF protection in form generated by Sonata Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143049/disable-csrf-protection-in-form-generated-by-sonata-admin)

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/3902